# Calculate all parameters of a triangle from some known partial lengths and angles

Tags: trigonometry

I have the problem described in this image (not to scale): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPYWp.png

A (partial cathetus), B (small, vertical cathetus) and C (which forms a 90º angle with hypotenuse) are known lengths (A=3, B=8, C=2 meters, inches, or whatever). I need to obtain the exact values of all sides and angles. The most important length I need is X, but I could calculate it myself once I know the at least one of the angles or lengths.

Could someone please tell me how to calculate at least one of the sides or angles?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would try to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the rest of the leg on which $A$ lies. Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{C^2}{Y^2} = \frac{B^2}{B^2 + (A+Y)^2}
&\iff B^2Y^2 = C^2(B^2 + A^2 + 2AY + Y^2)\\
&\iff (B^2 - C^2)Y^2 - 2AC^2Y - C^2(A^2 + B^2) = 0.\end{align}$$

Using the quadratic formula,

$$\begin{align}
Y & = \dfrac{2AC^2 \pm \sqrt{4A^2C^4 + 4(B^2-C^2)C^2(A^2+B^2)}}{2(B^2-C^2)}
\\ & = \dfrac{AC^2 \pm \sqrt{A^2C^4 + A^2B^2C^2 + B^4C^2 - A^2C^4 - B^2C^4}}{B^2-C^2}
\\ &= \dfrac{AC^2 \pm C \sqrt{A^2B^2 + B^4  - B^2C^2}}{B^2-C^2}
\\ &= \dfrac{AC^2 \pm BC \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 - C^2}}{B^2-C^2}.
\end{align}$$
We know $B>C$ since $C$'s triangle is similar to the overall triangle and embedded in it, so the radical is always real.  Also $BC \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 - C^2} > ABC > AC^2$, and $Y$ is positive, so the plus case gives us the only solution:

$$Y = \dfrac{AC^2 + BC \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 - C^2}}{B^2-C^2}.$$

Then $\dfrac{Y}{A+Y} = \dfrac{X}{B}$, so $X = \dfrac{BY}{A+Y}$.

Answer (score -1):

May be this can help you in simplifying your problem
[image: Notations]

Comment: From where do you get the 45°?

Comment: By joining unknow X line with A+A' gives a rectangle (i.e 90° angle) so line crossing it will gives 45°.

Comment: Thats right, but the crossing line gives us 45° only squares (?)

Comment: @ulead86 Yeah square has 45° and also rectangle has so... Rectangle is defined as "A rectangle is a four-sided shape where every angle is a right angle (90°). Also opposite sides are parallel and of equal length".

Comment: I don't see how 45º can be right. If you take a longer B, A' becomes smaller and that angle you say it's 45º would become wider.

Comment: @ulead86
Yeah guys you are right. I was confused with that. Thanks